# Minimum number of chains in a partially ordered set

Tags: order-theory

Imagine we have a partially ordered set like $(X,R)$. So, a set like $X$ is partially ordered by a relation like $R$.

We define $\delta(X):=$minimum number of chains in $X$ which covers poset

My Question is :
1. How many ways can i partition $X$ to $\delta(X)$ chains?
2. Can $\delta(X)$ be calculated by an algorithm of formula? If so, how?

Comment: @bof I'm not sure about my second question. I'll delete it for now, but the first question is more important :)

Comment: @bof i don't know how to say what is the meaning of that second question, but i think what you guessed is true

Comment: @bof my question is like this question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622109/finding-the-minimum-number-of-chains-of-a-given-poset-partially-ordered-set but the difference is that here, we don't have one special poset.

Comment: @bof i'm sorry about that :) i'll make edit

Comment: By [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem) $\delta(X),$ the minimum number of chains needed to cover the (finite) partially ordered set $X,$ is equal to the maximum size of an *antichain* in $X,$ meaning, a set of pairwise incomparable elements; this number is called the *width* of $X.$ That's the best answer I know to your second question. I don't know anything about the first question.

Comment: @arman regarding the first question I think there won't be a simple way to count them, consider $\mathcal{P}(\{0,1\})$,partially ordered by inclusion, with or without the empty set, in both cases the biggest antichain has 2 elements, but the number of ways you can cover the poset with $2$ chains is different

Comment: @Alessandro I understand what you say. One thing i want to add is that if there exists an isomorphism between two ways, we say they are equal.

Comment: You should indicate a little more what you know about the subject, in particular the results/theorems that are known and the limits of their scope. Have you seen the exceptional book "Additive Combinatorics" of Terence Tao (Field medal) and Van Vu, Cambridge U.P. 2006 ?